# Outlook last synchronisation location

Tags: outlook, exchange-server, lync-2013

We have a requirement to show persons location/work location in the last week and show him on the website when webpage is opened. We have a process mandate that every employee should visit this website and mark the attendance of last week. To get this information, can we pull the last synchronisation date time and location/IP Address or an individual from exchange server or Lync server?

Answer (score 0):

It depends how your users are actually connecting if they are using Outlook Anywhere or OWA then you should be able to use the Logs on Exchange to grab the Client IpAddress being used which you should then be able to derive their location. I would start by looking at the Log Parser Studio which has a lot of precanned reports http://blogs.technet.com/b/exchange/archive/2012/03/07/introducing-log-parser-studio.aspx and then look at customising your own solution.

Another alternative method that would rely on them having sent a messages in the last week is you could use EWS to derive it from their sent email eg http://gsexdev.blogspot.com.au/2012/10/geolocating-users-last-send-location.html

Cheers
Glen